# Phonegap Duration on video

Tags: javascript, android, ios, video, cordova

Hi I know this has been asked before on other questions but since phonegap is now on 2.9 it was supposed to have changed and allowed the duration feature on Android/iOs. I am trying to get set the duration of a video I want it set to three seconds-this is how I set that up-

```
function captureVideo() 
{
    //
    // Launch device video recording application, 
    // allowing user to capture up to 2 video clips
    //
    var options = { duration: 10, limit: 3 };
    navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(captureSuccess, captureError, options);    
}
```

and i call it by

```
<button type="button" name="test" onclick="captureVideo();" class="css3button">Test</button>
```

Its not working. is the duration still not available for android or ios??

Comment: Found out it was a bug that was missed in 2.9.0 and will be fixed for 3.0.0